# Problem using matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm a TeX noobie; just been using it to type up my math homework for the past week.

It's really annoying using arrays so I asked my teacher how to quickly do matrices and he said something about macros but then he also mentioned "`pmatrix`".

I went home and looked it up and literally copied and pasted some code but it always brings up an error. Here is a sample small document that produces the error I'm talking about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on? Thank you!

Comment: `\pmatrix` is defined in `amsmath`, so you need to say `\usepackage{amsmath}`.  (welcome to tex.sx.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was that the OP had not loaded the relevant package.

Comment: Should I just delete it instead @Andrew?

Comment: I think that it is up to you. You had a problem and you found out how to fix it because of Barbara's comment. Quite likely some one else will have the same issue in the future and will across your question and find it helpful. Closing the question is just a way of saying that your question has been dealt with even though there is no (accepted) answer.

Comment: Okay, I shall keep it then in case other noobies find this :)